# Jquery function onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick, html

How to add jquery function onclick with the span?

Now I have such span where I would like to add submit function to it:

```
    <input type="radio" name="language" id="engl" value="Engl" checked>
    <span class="division" onclick="document.getElementById('engl').checked = true">English</span>
```

I tried to add in my code that:

```
    $('span.division').change(function() {
    $('#search-form').submit();
    });
```

But there is no result. And of course I tried to add "name" to "span" it has no result too. Here is my jquery-code:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
    $('input[name=language]').change(function() {
    $('#search-form').submit();
});
    $("form#search-form").submit(function(){
    $("#results").fadeOut();
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        url: "search.php",
        success: function(msg)
    {
    $("#results").html(msg);
    $("#results").fadeIn();
    }
    });
    return false;
    });
});
 </script>
```

Where is my mistake? And how could I do it properly?

Comment: span not changed :) it clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the jQuery `on()` method with the event `click` instead of change:

```
$('span.division').on("click", function() {
   $('#search-form').submit();
});
```

Note however, that this might interfere with the click event you defined on your span via the inline `onclick="..."`!

Comment: Thanks so much! What a silly mistake. I realized it too late.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `click` event instead of change event for the span and move the submit binding functionality to the document `ready`. I just did some clean up with your code. This should work.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){

       $('span.division').click(function() {
          $('#search-form').submit();
       });

       $("form#search-form").submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#results").fadeOut();
            $.ajax({
               type:"GET",
               data: $(this).serialize(),
               url: "search.php",
               success: function(msg){
                          $("#results").html(msg).fadeIn();                       
                     }
            }); 
      }); 

  });
 </script>
```